# workaround for db.getCollectionNames() returning empty list for mongo clients predating Mongo 3.0

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Quoting the [manual from `db.getCollectionNames()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#considerations);

> For MongoDB 3.0 deployments using the WiredTiger storage engine, if you run db.getCollectionNames() from a version of the mongo shell before 3.0 or a version of the driver prior to 3.0 compatible version, db.getCollectionNames() will return no data, even if there are existing collections. For more information, see WiredTiger and Driver Version Compatibility.

Basically I have a large project where our mongo client is <3.0 and our mongo db is now on >3.0 with wiredtiger. I have been in the process of updating our spring to accomodate this change, but finding too many things breaking. Is there another way to handle this call without upgrading any jars?

sorry I am new to mongo so I have googled a lot but found nothing useful, other than upgrade to a new mongo client.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Your Mongo client is < 3.0"?"*. Because I think you are misunderstanding the intent of the documentation. You mention Java in the tags, so which version of the Java library is actually in use? It would need to be very very old. Note that a 2.x "Java Driver" is **not** what the message is talking about, because that would actually be **compatible** as "supporting >3.0". There also should be little to no backwards breaking changes in API unless it was indeed very very old. And from memory, spring-mongodb did not even exist at a point where it would make a difference.

Comment: My Mongo client would be the MongoClient.java from the mongo-java-driver jar. It was on ~2.4 and I upgraded it to 3.0 which started to break a lot of things, mainly revolving around tests and some mongo queries. I also upgraded spring-mongodb from 1.3.0.RELEASE to 1.5.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Last time I checked the 2.x driver series was [completely compatible with MongoDB 3.x releases](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility) at least the `2.13` and `2.14` most recent releases. You actually seem to be quoting the "MongoDB **Server** version", which is a completely different thing, since there never was a 2.4 version of the Java Driver.

Comment: At any rate it's not at all clear what you are asking without a reproducible example. I would suggest first actually reading the available compatibility matrix information as a first step and making any upgrades as actually required. Generally speaking they would appear to be **none** merely for changing an underlying server from 2.4 to 3.0. The only actual "breaking change" I personally am aware of there revolves around "authentication", and you can always "downgrade" that until you have a handle on updating your codebase.

Comment: Also since you actually really only mention the "mongo shell" method in your question, then it sounds like you need to update your "client" software from the `mongo-shell` and `mongo-tools` packages. You can use latest releases of these, since they are actually equipped to connect both to most recent versions as well as older versions of MongoDB. That usually is the way of things. As for any "Java Code", if you believe there is a problem then provide an example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)